# Possible refactoring in binary tree

Tags: python, tree

I implemented a binary tree in Python, with preorder/postorder/inorder traversal methods.

```
class BinaryTree(object):

    def __init__(self, rootObj):
        self.key = rootObj
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None

    def insertLeftChild(self, newNode):
        if self.leftChild == None:
            self.leftChild = BinaryTree(newNode)
        else:
            newBinaryTree = BinaryTree(newNode)
            newBinaryTree.leftChild = self.leftChild
            self.leftChild = newBinaryTree
        return self.leftChild

    def insertRightChild(self, newNode):
        if self.rightChild == None:
            self.rightChild = BinaryTree(newNode)
        else:
            newBinaryTree = BinaryTree(newNode)
            newBinaryTree.rightChild = newNode
            self.rightChild = newBinaryTree
        return self.rightChild

    def getRoot(self):
        return self.key

    def setRoot(self, obj):
        self.key = obj

    def getLeftChild(self):
        return self.leftChild

    def getRightChild(self):
        return self.rightChild

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.key

    # DFS traversal techniques.
    @classmethod
    def preorder(cls, node):
        if node == None: return False
        print node
        cls.preorder(node.getLeftChild())
        cls.preorder(node.getRightChild())

    @classmethod
    def inorder(cls, node):
        if node == None: return False
        cls.inorder(node.getLeftChild())
        print node
        cls.inorder(node.getRightChild())

    @classmethod
    def postorder(cls, node):
        if node == None: return False
        cls.inorder(node.getLeftChild())
        cls.inorder(node.getRightChild())
        print node


def buildTree():
    root = BinaryTree('a')
    firstLeft = root.insertLeftChild('b')
    firstRight = root.insertRightChild('c')
    firstLeft.insertRightChild('d')
    firstRight.insertLeftChild('e')
    firstRight.insertRightChild('f')
    return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    binaryTree = buildTree()
    print 'Preorder'
    print BinaryTree.preorder(binaryTree)
    print 'Inorder'
    print BinaryTree.inorder(binaryTree)
    print 'Postorder'
    print BinaryTree.postorder(binaryTree)
```

Also, I'd like to know how go about unit testing this code. I'd appreciate guidance and links to relevant documentation.

Comment: You call `inorder` in `postorder`. Shouldn't it be `postorder` instead...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As evidenced by the bug in Rev 1, the inconsistent naming between `getRoot()`/`setRoot()` and `self.key` is a trap that you've created for yourself.

Getters and setters would be better done using the [`@property` decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).  Follow the convention in the documentation:

```
class BinaryTree(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
        self.left_child = self.right_child = None

    @property
    def obj(self):
        """The datum stored in the node."""
        return self._obj

    @obj.setter
    def obj(self, value):
        self._obj = value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.obj)    # <-- Simpler than %s interpolation

    …
```

---

Your traversal algorithms should not have a `print` statement, as they would be useless for anything other than printing to `sys.stdout`.  Instead, they should [`yield`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) each result.  The caller can then choose to print them or do whatever it pleases.

```
for obj in pre_order(root):
    print obj
```

---

A nice way to write simple unit tests and provide documentation at the same time is to use the [`doctest` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html).

Comment: I tried `yield` in place of the print but I am getting only first element, maybe my function is recursive which is returning another generator. Updated the above post to include the new method definition.

Comment: How to use `yield` in a recursive function?

Comment: Exactly like I wrote. Change `print` to `yield`, then iterate using a `for` loop.

Answer (score 4):

A few comments:

- There is no explanation anywhere of what is supposed to be happening. Consider adding [docstrings](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to your methods; I like the [Google style](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_google.html), but others are available.
- Your code isn't compliant with the [style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/); methods, attributes and instances should be named using `lower_case_with_underscores` not `mixedCase`.
- It's not clear why `inorder`, `preorder` and `postorder` are *class*, rather than *instance*, methods (this could be explained in docstrings!) `binaryTree.inorder()` seems much neater than `BinaryTree.postorder(binaryTree)`.
- `buildTree`, on the other hand, probably *should* be a class method, rather than a standalone function (`binaryTree = BinaryTree.buildTree()`).

Comment: Sure, I will try to follow the style guide and update the code also, buildTree is just a test function.

Comment: Regarding ```inorder```, ```preorder``` I had some confusion but I thought in terms of functional programming.

Comment: What do you mean *"in terms of functional programming"*?

Comment: Simply, I didn't wanted to tie that method to a particular instance i.e. given a obj of BinaryTree type it could traverse it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a issue with how you are handling the payload for the tree.  The property for it is called "Key" which is okay, but the constructor argument is calling it an object.  So are we storing a value or a data structure?  If it is a data structure, then payload would probably be a better name.

I also see problems with the Insert methods.  The argument named `newNode` is misleading  (along with `rootObj` in the constructor).  I'm assuming an instance of BinaryTreeNode (which isn't present) or `BinaryTree` to be passed in here because of the name of the argument.  Also in these methods the abstraction barrier is broken by directly manipulating the new binary tree property (`newBinaryTree.rightChild = newNode`) instead of calling its own insert method but not a huge problem.  If you made the left and right child private/protected members, this could break your code (based on language used).

The `getRoot` and `setRoot` methods are wrong as well.  `getRoot` should be a recursive function that navigates from a given node up the tree to the top most node.  Instead it is accessing the payload of the node.  Set root isn't taking the tree twig and breaking it off from the parent tree.  Instead they are acting as getters and setters for the payload of the node.

If you want the `getRoot` and `setRoot` methods to do what the names suggests, you need to add a reference back to the parent tree when inserting nodes.